# Calling an SQL query inside an SQL query while loop

Tags: php, html, sql, database

```
<?
$id = ($_GET["id"]);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM champions WHERE id=$id") or die("Error: " .       mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$name = $row[1];
$icon = $row[2];
$picon = $row[4];
$passive = $row[5];
$qicon = $row[6];
$qskill = $row[7];
$wicon = $row[8];
$wskill = $row[9];
$eicon = $row[10];
$eskill = $row[11];
$ricon = $row[12];
$rskill = $row[13];
$ad = $row[14];
$as = $row[15];
$arm = $row[16];
$mr = $row[17];
$mov = $row[18];
$hp = $row[19];
$mana = $row[20]; 


$secquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM icons WHERE picid=1") or die("Error: " .    mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($secquery)){

$hpicon = $row[1];
$manaicon = $row[2];

echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
echo '<div class="row-fluid">';
echo '<div class="span6">';
echo '<table id="noborder">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($icon) . '" /></td>';
echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';  
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
}

echo '<div class="span6">';
echo '<table id="noborder" >';
echo '<tr><td id="celltop" width="64px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' .    base64_encode($picon) . '" /> </td><td>' . $passive . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td id="celltop" width="64px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($qicon) . '" /> </td><td>' . $qskill . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td id="celltop" width="64px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($wicon) . '" /> </td><td>' . $wskill . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td id="celltop" width="64px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($eicon) . '" /> </td><td>' . $eskill . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td id="celltop" width="64px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($ricon) . '" /> </td><td>' . $rskill . '</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

}

```
?>
```

I have a 117 different pages. What I'm trying to do is call icons from a separate table which will be the same for all 117 pages, that's why I've stored them in a different table. But I need to call the icons among the data from the other table.

Answer (score 1):

even if you get this working this many hits on your database is a bad idea and will be very slow I would re engineer this to only hit the database once or at most twice to get all the values you need

Possible ideas

OPT A
write view that contains everything you need joint originally from the icons table then to the champions table either duplicating the champions for each icon then just create a couple of loops

OPT B
get all the icons then and pop them in a class structure to then retrieve as you need them from memory rather than per record.